# Gurobi - Get status message by status code?

Tags: python, gurobi

Is there a way to get the status message using a status code? For error codes I can easily get the message by catching the exception and accessing its `.message` attribute, however for statuses I only get the code from:

```
model.status
```

It seems like the messages are stored in the Gurobi library since it prints out a message when something happens, for example encountering an infeasible model, but I don't see a way of accessing the message itself, i.e. storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API function to retrieve the internal status message, but it's fairly simple to set up a message dict yourself for that purpose.  Assuming that you have imported `GRB`, one could do:

```
>>> # TODO add more status codes here...
>>> msgdict = {GRB.OPTIMAL : 'Optimal', GRB.INFEASIBLE : 'Infeasible model'}
>>> model.optimize()
>>> print msgdict[m.status]
Optimal
```